# Java Interações

Tags: java

Bom dia a todos caros programadores.

Estou iniciando recentemente a liguagem JAVA, gostaria de saber se é possivel realizar como no javascript interatividade do usuario com o software.

Como por exemplo um hover que desfoca uma imagem, ou que muda a cor de um objeto, algo neste sentido. 
Venho da linguagem web utilizava javascript, css e html e é muito facil realizar esses procedimentos nestas linguagem.

Comment: Consegue sim, Raul. Java é uma linguagem poderosa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Até consegue. Quando se desenvolve em Java para Desktop é possível criar diferentes interações com o usuário já que existe o conceito das janelas que são construídas em Java mesmo então tem muitas funções que criam esses efeitos. Só que na Web o Java serve como uma linguagem backend, ou seja, rodando no servidor e transparente para o usuário, então o papel de interação é do Javascript, CSS, etc.

O Java na web vai servir mesmo para processar os dados e fazer as lógicas. A interação com o usuário normalmente não é o foco do Java para a web.

Para o Java Desktop é bastante comum usar os recursos Swing ou JavaFX (mais novo) e as IDEs como o Eclipse e Netbeans deixam você criar as telas apenas "arrastando e soltando", para poder se preocupar só com a lógica por trás.